# How to stop reading input when a certain character is reached

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Let's assume somebody is writing some text. My program has to scan that text and then print all the characters under each other. However, it should only read the input until * appears. So when the input is "Hello*darling", it should only read "Hello". I used the * as an argument in while loop, but my program scans "Hello*" instead of "Hello". How do I get rid of the *?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c1;
    while (c1!='*'){
        scanf("%c", &c1);
        printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Here you're using `c1` uninitializted: `while (c1!='*'){`.

Comment: you read the new value for c1 after the check if it's "*". You then proceed to print. After that the loop starts again, it check if the character matches. It's not until this moment that the '*' van be detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c1;
    while ((c1=getchar())!=EOF && c1!='*'){
       printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: and this way, there is no undefined behavior, because `c1` is always initialized (see @Blaze answer) :)

Comment: `char c1;` should be `int c1;` and `while ((c1=getchar())!='*')` should be `while ((c1=getchar())!=EOF && c1!='*')`.

Comment: There is still a typo: `'EOF'` should be `EOF`. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically I was missing the EOF argument. Can you explain why is that important? I don't quite understand why does that eliminate the *, from what I know, EOF is the "end of file", so it should be the end of input right? Does the "while" tell the program: "scan until you reach * and * is the end of file"?

Comment: No, that means: "While the input has not ended (`(c1=getchar())!=EOF`), and the input is different from '*' (`c1!='*'`) do ...". The first part is just a safe guard to avoid an undefined behavior by trying to read an input who has ended.

Answer (score 3):

You could switch the `scanf` and `printf` statements and put an initial `scanf` before the loop:

```
int main()
{
    char c1 = '\0';
    do {
        printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
        if (scanf(" %c", &c1) != 1)
            return -1;
    } while (c1 != '*');
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that as your program currently is, there's not just the issue with printing the `*`, but it's undefined behavior because `c1` is uninitialized in the first run of `c1 != '*'`.

Comment: It should check the `scanf` return value (in two places).

Comment: @IanAbbott Good suggestion. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Involving the for unknown reasons unloved cousin `do {...} while (...)` would be much more elegant.

Comment: @alk You're right. I keep forgetting this loop exists. :)

Comment: In any case for each time the user hits the enter-key the loop does and additional iteration reading the new-line entered by hitting the enter-key. Use `scanf(" %c, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scanf()` *and* doing complete error checking and logging:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */

  {
    int r;

    {
      char c1 = 0;
      while (EOF != (r = fscanf(stdin, " %c", &c1)) && c1 != '*')
      {
        if (1 != r)
        {
          fputs("Invalid input. Retrying ...", stderr);
        }
        else
        {
          printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
        }
      }
    }

    {
      int errno_save = errno;

      if ((EOF == r) && ferror(stdin))
      {
        errno = errno_save;
        perror("scanf() failed");
        result = EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use while or for when you want to check the condition at the start of the loop, do ... until if you want to check at the end. If you want to check in the middle, I prefer an infinite loop ("while(TRUE)" or "for(;;)") and using if/break in the middle. Taking your loop, that would be:

```
while (TRUE){
    scanf("%c", &c1);
    if (c1=='*') {
        break;
    }
    printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
}
```

Some people don't like that, an alternative is to make that a function, using return instead of break:

```
boolean get_and_print_if_not_end() {
    scanf("%c", &c1);
    if (c1=='*') {
        return true;
    }
    printf("c1: %c \n", c1);
    return false;
}
```

You'd call that in a basic while loop:

```
while (!get_and_print_if_not_end()) {
    // Nothing to do here.
}
```

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646148/how-to-stop-reading-input-when-a-certain-character-is-reached/58646792#comment103598588_58646212) applies here as well.

Comment: Yes, it should. scanf() is a vast topic by itself, I just wanted to talk about loop conditions here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    int main()
    {
        char string;
        do
        {
            printf("String is :%c\n",string);
            if(scanf("%c",&string)!=1)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }while(string!='*');
        return 0
}
```

Here:

---

First, it will get the string character and compare it to  * character if the character is no found it will print the character. else it finds it will return 0 and the program will be eliminated.

---